# Custom query from Symfony controller returns null

Tags: symfony, controller, dql

I'm trying to build a custom query from symfony controller but it returns null. When I execute this query on phpMyadmin it returns results.

SyntheseController.php:

```
     * @Route("/synthese/categorie/{period}", name="categoriesSyntheseByMonthAndYear")
     * 
     */
    public function getCategorieSyntheseByMonthAndYear(String $period, Request $request): Response
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $periodArray = explode("-",$period);

        $month = $periodArray[0];
        $year = $periodArray[1];

        $jsonData = [];

        $sql = "SELECT categories.nom_categorie, sum(depenses.montant_depense) AS montant "
            . "FROM sous_categories "
            . "LEFT JOIN depenses ON depenses.sous_categorie_id = sous_categories.id "
            . "LEFT JOIN categories ON sous_categories.categories_id = categories.id "
            . "WHERE categories.nom_categorie "
            . "IN (SELECT DISTINCT nom_categorie FROM categories WHERE 1) AND depenses.mois_depense = '" . $month . "' AND depenses.annee_depense = '" . $year . "' GROUP BY categories.nom_categorie;";

        $query = $em->createQuery($sql);
        $syntheseCategories = $query->getResult();

        var_dump($syntheseCategories);

        foreach($syntheseCategories as $syntheseCategorie){
            echo $syntheseCategorie['nom_categorie'];
            $jsonData[] = [
                'name' => $syntheseCategorie['nom_categorie'],//$syntheseCategories['nom_categorie'],
                'y' => (double) $syntheseCategories['montant'],
            ];
        }
        return new JsonResponse($jsonData); 
    }
```

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong ?
How can we write this on DQL ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really want DQL or do you just want to get the SQL query to work?  If SQL then use $em->getConnection to get Doctrines connection object which is just a thin wrapper over PDO.  Assuming your extremely insecure query is correct then the code should work.  Lookup Doctrine's Database Access Layer (DBAL) for details.

Comment: Thanks, could you please tell me how I can write this with DQL ? It seems to be difficult for me, I'm a beginner. Thank you.

Comment: DQL is not meant to replace SQL.  DQL is designed to get objects out of the database using fairly simple queries.  For your case involving sums and group bys and nested queries etc. SQL is a better choice.